# Custom actionbar button coding doubts

Tags: android

I have made a custom action-bar :

[image]

Now I want to write the code for the buttons that I have added
like home,back,forward etc.

So do I make a new java file to write the code?
or do i write the click event codes in the MainActivity?
Also any other changes I will have to make to other files like the manifest or MainActivity?

**My MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent launchactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    potraitWebview.class); // **customactionbar is used in this activity**
            startActivity(launchactivity);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's the code of the activity where im using the customactionbar

```
public class potraitWebview extends Activity {
WebView web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.potraitlayout);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.customtitlebar);
.
.
}
```

Comment: Are all the above buttons inside main.xml menu file?

Comment: the 3 buttons in the action bar are inside another xml
which i use for the custom action bar

Comment: If you have successfully added the button to actionbar, Then whats you wana next? do you need to make these buttons clickable?

Comment: Just wanted to know whether i can write the onclick event code in the activity on which im applying the customactionbar or should i make a new java file for the same?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom, menu);//Another xml file name

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id)
        {
        case R.id.backwardId:
            Intent back=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BackwardActivity.class);
            startActivity(back);
            return true;
        case R.id.Home:
            Intent home=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(home);
        return true;
        case R.id.ForwardId:
            Intent forward=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ForwardActivity.class);
            startActivity(forward);
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```

Comment: Please don't just dump some code without any form of explanation. Please take a look at the [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide to see how you could improve this answer.